# What's wrong with "terminal cd ." in vim 8.1?

Tags: terminal, vim8

`terminal cd .` results in following weird error in the terminal buffer:

```
executing job failed: No such file or directory
```

The same error appears for `term_start('cd .')`. It doesn't matter which directory I `cd` to, the error doesn't change.

If I execute `terminal` without command, then execute `cd .` in the opened terminal, everything works fine.

I'm using vim8.1 include patches 1-1282 on Ubuntu 16.04.6 .

Based on help from comment and answer, I changed the command to

```
terminal bash -c 'cd .'
```

but it results in following error:

```
.': -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''
.': -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

buffer name of the terminal is:

```
!bash -c 'cd .'
```

If I replace the single quotes with double quotes the command works. But why?

Comment: Im not sure i understand why you would do this—the terminal would just execute a cd and then exit, so the net effect for you is absolutely nothing.

Comment: I need to `cd` to `bin` and do something, i thought that doesn't change the problem, so i make the case as simple as possible.

Comment: Gotcha. That makes sense.

Comment: I believe `cd` is actually an internal shell command and not actually a binary. See also this answer: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/50025/303213 and here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/116972/303213

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt Thanks, very helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on Chris’s comments on the OP, I would make the shell do the work, using a level of indirection:

```
terminal bash -c "cd wherever && do_something"
```

The issue is that the bare `:terminal` command doesn’t ever execute a shell—it executes the name of the external program you give it (which, by default, happens to be the shell). So, `terminal cd .` tries to run a command on disk named `cd`. For reasons, you don’t have one, and it wouldn’t work if you did.

Comment: Not working well, see update.

Comment: @dedowsdi dang. Must be vim’s command line doing something weird with the quotes. Ill check it out in the morning

Comment: use double quotes. not sure what single quotes do here.

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt theyre just easier to type. I wouldn’t have thought it made a difference in this particular case

Comment: `:terminal` run `command` as `job`, `job_start` split `command` by white space and pass result list to `execvp()`, only arguments in double quotes can contain white space. Don't know the reason behind the choice of double quotes, but i can settle for that.