# use pipe symbol in vim :term command

Tags: terminal, terminal-buffer

recently i stumpled over vim :terminal mode.
i am really exited about that.
now i wanted to ask, how i can create a mapping, which sends a command, including a pipe symbol to :terminal?
it should look like this:

```
nnoremap <leader>hcu :term echo "hello" | grep "ll"<CR>
```

But gives me something like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1U0EG.png

Any hints, on how i can use commands like this with the :term command?

Comment: However, there is one noteworthy aspect that is not covered here. The command you tell the `:term` command to be run, won't be processed by the shell, so output redirection like using a `|` (pipe) cannot work. The :term command expects the command provided to be executed directly (see also [this question](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/19867)).

Comment: So you have to provide the shell command to be run directly and make sure to use double quotes to quote the necessary parts, as single quotes might not always work.