# Opening a terminal window and executing the cd command

Tags: terminal

In my current vim session, I would like to open a new terminal window and immediately execute the cd command in that terminal to change to a specific directory. I have tried

```
:terminal cd /home/me/folder
```

But this does not work, and gives me the message

```
executing job failed: No such file or directory
```

How can I do this?

Comment: I'm surprised that fails. Perhaps because `cd` is a builtin shell command. If there's really no direct way to do this I'd probably use a workaround like a custom command: `com! -nargs=1 Cdterm lcd <args> | term`. Then `:Cdterm somedir`.

Comment: Duplicate of this question: https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/19867/71

Comment: If relevant, try using https://github.com/kassio/neoterm in neovim. No such problems.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with [B Layer's comment](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/26782/opening-a-terminal-window-and-executing-the-cd-command#comment47731_26782): It fails because `cd` is a builtin command in most modern systems. That means it does not exist as a standalone command such as `/bin/echo` and `/usr/bin/gcc`.

Then, a workaround is to invoke the shell to execute the command.

```
:ter sh -c "cd /home/me/folder;sh"
```

If `sh` does not resolve to your preferred shell, substitute it by the latter, for example, Bash:

```
:ter bash -c "cd /home/me/folder;bash"
```

As you can see, the shell is invoked again at the end, because the first
shell would quit immediately after executing `cd`, leaving an unmodified and useless terminal buffer behind.

Comment: Awesome, thanks!

Comment: Now that I think about it, even if cd wasn't a built-in, I don't think :terminal cd would have the effect I want, since it would only leave you with a window showing an "empty" buffer, and the shell would have been exited, which isn't really what I wanted anyway. So to me, the key here is really invoking the the shell a second time as you are doing above.

Comment: @JamesHungerford You are welcome! Yes, I imagined that was your case. You may want to [edit] the question to explicitly include the requirement of staying with the shell after executing the `cd` command. The linked duplicate question does not seem to have that requirement.