# How can I open a split terminal with :term and then run a command in that terminal?

Tags: terminal, functions

I'm trying to write a function to open a split terminal in Vim and then run the current file in that terminal. A non-working example trying to explain what I'm trying to do is

```
function! Foo()
    :bel term
    %
endfunction
```

This just opens up the terminal. I tried with another command, `dir`, and it seems it's fails because `dir` is not a Vim command, so it's still trying to run things in Vim rather than the terminal. I also tried putting the command on the same line e.g. `:bel term %` but I get an error:

```
Error detected while processing function Foo:
line 2:
CreateProcess failed
```

And the terminal doesn't even open.

I also tried

```
function! Foo()
    :bel term
    !dir
endfunction
```

though that had the expected result of essentially running `!dir` and then returning me to a split window with nothing in the terminal there.

I've also tried to use the `feedkeys()` function but I can't find a way to automatically pass the file name in.

I can't see anything relevant on `:help terminal`. I've also found two relevant posts ([post 1](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/26782/opening-a-terminal-window-and-executing-the-cd-command), [post 2](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/19867/whats-wrong-with-terminal-cd-in-vim-8-1)) but both seem to use Linux/bash and I'm on Windows, and those solutions aren't working.

How could I achieve this? If it's relevant I'm running Vim on Windows through cmd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each line in vimscript is a vim command, not a series of keystrokes. Running `:terminal` doesn't automatically mean any following commands will be sent to the terminal buffer.

In order to send keystrokes to a terminal, we need its buffer number and `term_sendkeys()`. The easiest way to get a terminal's buffer number programatically is to start it with `term_start()`:

```
function Foo() abort
  " replace with let if your vim is old
  const term_buf = term_start(&shell)
  call term_sendkeys(term_buf, expand('#')."\<CR>")
endfunction
```

You can also use method syntax in this case:

```
call term_start(&shell)->term_sendkeys(expand('#')."\<CR>")
```

- `expand('#')` gets the previous files name (`term_start()` has already switched to the terminal buffer)
- `."\<CR>"` embeds a carriage-return (enter) keypress, too
- `term_start()` takes a fair number of options, so you can use, *e.g.,* `#{vertical: v:true}` for a vertical split.

When you do `:terminal %`, it tries to run the file expanded to by `%` as a program; it's possible the file isn't found (*e.g.*, if the file is in the current directory and that directory is not in `PATH`). Using `:terminal %:p` might work around that.

Comment: That function you posted does open a terminal, but returns the file path of cmd rather than the file name. However, I managed to fix it by with `const file_name = expand('%')` and then `call term_start(&shell)->term_sendkeys(file_name)`! So thank you for that. A couple more questions: (1) how do I send an Enter keypress afterwards? Currently it fills the filename in the terminal but doesn't run it. (2) Is there a way to make the terminal split to be below or alongside the code, rather than above it, similar to `:bel term` and `:vert term`?

Comment: Also, `:terminal %:p` sadly does not work, and gives the same error as the similar attempts mentioned in the question.

Comment: Ick, good call on the file-name—`term_start()` switches windows, so the old one is lost. I'll use `#` here for the alternate file. For an enter keypress, you need a string with `"\<cr>"` in it probably. Have a look at `term_start()`s options and see if there's a splitting option.

Comment: Hadn't seen `#` before, good to know! Much cleaner. As for the `term_start()` options: I'd already found them so I knew there was an option for a vertical split called `vertical`, but being new to Vim/Vimscript I couldn't figure out the syntax. After an embarassing amount of time I've finally got it: `term_start(&shell, {'vertical' : 1})`. Thanks for all the help!

Comment: Good stuff. I haven't spent near enough time playing around with `:term` and all that goes with it.

Comment: I haven’t done too much with it other than [simpl](https://github.com/benknoble/vim-simpl), which i have more plans for, but `:terminal`+tmux is pretty much my daily “i need to run something” when I’m in vim @BLayer

Comment: @D.BenKnoble Actually, that's probably why I haven't spent much time with it...99% of the time that I'm in (terminal) Vim it's in tmux and my custom stuff involving "shell from Vim" mostly predates `:term` and/or is easier to do with `:!`.